# how to make headless chrome support window.print?

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, pdf, printing

I use chrome+java+selenium to run command "window.print" and let it choose “save as pdf” by default.if I comments the "chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");",it works fine. If add the headless mode,it doesn't work. Is anyone know how to make headless chrome support window.print and save as pdf automatically? thanks

```
String appState = "{\"selectedDestinationId\": \"Save as PDF\",\"version\": 2,\"isGcpPromoDismissed\":false}";  
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
            chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", "/app/data/pdfs/");
            chromePrefs.put("download.directory_upgrade", "true");
            //chromePrefs.put("printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState", profiles);
            chromePrefs.put("printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState",appState);
            chromePrefs.put("savefile.default_directory", "/app/data/pdfs/");
            chromePrefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
            chromePrefs.put("directory_upgrade", true);
            chromePrefs.put("default_directory", "/app//data/pdfs/");
            chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--kiosk-printing");
```

Comment: Your problem was solved, checkout Vikas's answer here:
https://superuser.com/questions/592974/how-to-print-to-save-as-pdf-from-a-command-line-with-chrome-or-chromium

Comment: @V.Somai that's not an answer: the OP wants to use printing for **Automated Testing** (through selenium, after some action), not simply printing a website to a pdf.